# How can I use JSON to save/load pygame.Group() objects?

Tags: python, json, pygame, save

I'm trying to make a save/load function to try and save/load the positions of blocks on-screen. These blocks are stored in a pygame Group called `blocks`.

Here is the portion of the code I use to save with json:

```
blocks_json_str = json.dumps(blocks, sort_keys = True, indent = 4)
os.path.join(saves_path, "inventory", "inventory.txt").write_text(blocks_json_str)
```

..and here is the code to load the data:

```
assert json.loads((os.path.join(saves_path, "inventory", "inventory.txt")).read_text()) == blocks
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Group' is not JSON serializable
```

Is there a good way to save/load Groups with JSON? If there is, what is it? If there's not, what is a good alternative for saving Groups?

Comment: You will have to write a function that transforms the `Group` object into `JSON serializable` objects (`list`,`dict`,`str`,`int`,`float`)

Comment: In that example I just save the relevant data (sprite positions, color, etc.) that can be serialized with the json module and then just recreate the sprites and add them to the group.